# Page refresh removes queryParams Angular Router

Tags: angular, angular-router, query-string

I access to an angular component with a route `myApp/contact` with some query params like so

```
<div routerLink="../contact" [queryParams]="{ filter: 'myFilter' }"> </div>
```

The query params are saved in a router state (implementation of RouterStateSerializer) so I can access them from my component and then display them.
When I navigate in the component, the url is now `myApp/contact?filter=myFilter`, which is good.

- If I refresh the page, the url is now `myApp/contact` without the queryParams but I can still see them displayed on the page.
- If I now refresh the page a second time, the url is again `myApp/contact` but now the queryParams are null when displayed on the page (which is logical because they weren't in the url anymore)

I noticed that when the route to `myApp/contact` is navigated, an another route request is made straight after @ngrx/router-store/navigated (see this 2nd request on capture below). **I do not know where this second navigation request comes from, but it is during this one that the queryParams seem to be lost**.

**The question is, why my queryParams disappear when I refresh the page ? Is it cause of a configuration somewhere ? Why are there two navigation requests ?**

[image]

These "2 navigation requests" occur only when I refresh this component page => none of my other pages have this behaviour (and I suspect it is because there are queryParams on this page)

I also have another Angular app which has some queryParams on some pages and I don't have the same behaviour when I refresh the page => the queryParams stay in the url, no matter the number of time I refresh the page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found what happened.
The second navigation came from my cookie management (CookieComponent)

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.router.navigate([{ outlets: { popup: isDisplayed ? 'cookie' : null } }]);
}
```

I don't really get why this second navigation occurs only when there are queryParams on the page. But refactoring this code as follow solved my problem

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    if (display) {
      this.router.navigate([{ outlets: { popup: 'cookie' } }]);
    }
}
```

So if you have a weird behaviour with your queryParams on a page, first check in your app if you have some `this.router.navigate` that may have been called during the page reload !

Answer (score 1):

By default query parameters are lost on subsequent navigation requests. Set the `queryParamsHandling` to `preserve` to keep them

```
<div routerLink="../contact" [queryParams]="{ filter: 'myFilter' }" queryParamsHandling="preserve"> </div>
```

Comment: Hi, I tried your suggestion but I still have the same behaviour with subsequent navigation requests

Answer (score -1):

I'm not getting this behaviour, my guess is you're doing something funky in the component. Access your query params in your component (whichever is connected to the `/component` path) using the `ActivatedRoute` service.

```js
  filter = '';

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.filter = this.route.snapshot.queryParams['filter'];
  }
```